# Deployment of Python Azure Function App fails: Error: Could not find the .NET Core project file

Tags: python, azure, function

I have issues with the redeployment of an Azure HTTP function written in python. I deployed the app successfully via VSC to azure multiple times. After a recent code change however the deployment fails.

See below the output:

```
07:36:30 ageuadffapproval: Starting deployment...
07:36:33 ageuadffapproval: Creating zip package...
07:36:33 ageuadffapproval: Zip package size: 9.43 kB
07:36:34 ageuadffapproval: Fetching changes.
07:36:35 ageuadffapproval: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/624525ca-de6d-40a4-b776-ca6f4e9377e2.zip (0.01 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
07:36:37 ageuadffapproval: Updating submodules.
07:36:38 ageuadffapproval: Preparing deployment for commit id '51050b0c-3'.
07:36:38 ageuadffapproval: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
07:36:38 ageuadffapproval: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
07:36:38 ageuadffapproval: Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
07:36:38 ageuadffapproval: Running oryx build...
07:36:38 ageuadffapproval: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.9 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
07:36:40 ageuadffapproval: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
07:36:40 ageuadffapproval: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
07:36:40 ageuadffapproval: Oryx Version: 0.2.20210120.1, Commit: 66c7820d7df527aaffabd2563a49ad57930999c9, ReleaseTagName: 20210120.1
07:36:40 ageuadffapproval: Build Operation ID: |QIo9nRCKUtA=.d31df99_
07:36:40 ageuadffapproval: Repository Commit : 51050b0c-3805-40d5-86de-62b35ed2ff80
07:36:40 ageuadffapproval: Detecting platforms...
07:36:41 ageuadffapproval: Error: Could not find the .NET Core project file.
07:36:43 ageuadffapproval: /opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.9 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
07:36:43 ageuadffapproval: Generating summary of Oryx build
07:36:43 ageuadffapproval: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
07:36:43 ageuadffapproval: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
07:36:43 ageuadffapproval: Deployment Failed.
07:36:50 ageuadffapproval: Deployment failed.
```

Any idea where this issue is coming from? As mentioned: minutes before the deployment fails issue I deployed the app multiple times successfully to the portal already.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried to reproduce the issue but still not getting any error as you by following the below mentioned workarounds.

- Created an azure function with HTTP Trigger using python and tested locally which is working fine .

[image]
[image]

*And then In VS CODE by selecting resource created a New Azure function application to deploy the function for the first time*.

***OUTPUT FOR REFERENCE:-***
[image]
[image]

***Tested first time deployment:-***
[image]

---

***After** that made some basic changes in our code then try to redeploy after restarting the VS CODE and Function which is created in local workspace saved and did the steps as below*;
[image]
[image]
[image]

***TESTED AFTER 2ND DEPLOYMENT:-***
[image]

***NOTE:-*** ***If you have deployed the same function again and again without any fail make sure that after changing the code save it then restart your VS code and also check that you have .net extension/Python extension and so on. And then Please try to redeploy again.***

For more information  please refer the below links:-

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENT**| [***Deploy Python Azure funciton Project to Azure***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=csharp#republish-project-files).
- *Similar on-going GitHub Issue Suggestion* |[***Unable to Deploy .Net6 Azure function***](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/1242#issuecomment-1050729304)
- **Blog**| [***Deploy Python apps to Azure Functions using Visual Studio Code***](https://www.sqlshack.com/deploy-python-apps-to-azure-functions-using-visual-studio-code/) by @*Aveek Das* .